# Dynamic Menu drops pages?

Tags: php, functions, menus

I've created a Dynamic Menu that highlights the selected page and colors for example the blog page "red" while the other links (home, about, contanct) remain white.

My question is how can I make the Dynamic Menu work when say the blog goes to /blog/page/2/ and have the blog remain red instead of dropping the highlight?

Here's the code for my menu.

```
< nav id="menu" class="mid" role="navigation">
  < ?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
< /nav>
```

Then, I register the menu inside the functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
    function register_my_menu() {
        register_nav_menu( 'primary-menu', __( 'Primary Menu' ) );
    }
```

Here's the CSS that highlights the .current-menu-item

`#menu .current-menu-item a {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }`

This is when the Menu is Active on example.com/work

[image: menu active]

This is when the Menu is Active on the example.com/blog *just the first blog page though
[image: menu active blog]

This is the menu when it switches to example.com/blog/page/2, example.com/work/showcase/website1337
[image: menu not active]

How, can I make it so that the Dynamic Menu detects that /page/2 is still associated with the parent page "/blog/, /work/" and is still highlighted like images 1 and 2?

Thanks :3

Answer (score 1):

Test:

```
#menu current_page_ancestor a { opacity: 1.0; }
```

Check this [Menu Item CSS Classes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Menu_Item_CSS_Classes)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the Codex for this! I think this will lead me in the right direction to getting this to work. I just have to figure out if my menu is even connecting the parent pages, because when I add say .current-menu-parent or .current_page_ancestor it's not highlighting it.